# removing a sharepoint solution duplicates entry in web.config?

Tags: 2010, feature, feature-activation, feature-receiver, feature-upgrade

My intentions is to be able to add and remove web.config changes when a solution is installed or uninstalled.

The code below and the powershell below works ALMOST as expected.

1. When I add sp solution, and then install sp solution, The web.config is modified and a new entry is added. Perfect!!!!

However the problem is that when I execute the powershell scripts to uninstall and remove the sp solution, The entry is added again, instead of being removed.

WEIRD!!!!

```
 public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                SPWebService contentService = SPWebService.ContentService;
                contentService.WebConfigModifications.Add(GetConfigModification());

                // Serialize the Web application state and propagate changes across the farm. 
                contentService.Update();

                // Save Web.config changes.
                contentService.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }


        // Uncomment the method below to handle the event raised before a feature is deactivated.

        public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                SPWebService contentService = SPWebService.ContentService;
                contentService.WebConfigModifications.Remove(GetConfigModification());

                // Serialize the Web application state and propagate changes across the farm. 
                contentService.Update();

                // Save Web.config changes.
                contentService.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Get configuration to add or remove
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public SPWebConfigModification GetConfigModification()
        {
            SPWebConfigModification modification = new SPWebConfigModification("authorizedType[@Assembly=\"MyCompany.CustomACtivities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=207090b9b3f674c8\"][@Namespace=\"MyCompany.CustomActivities\"][@TypeName=\"*\"][@Authorized=\"True\"]", "configuration/System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler/authorizedTypes");
            modification.Owner = "MyCompany.CustomActivities";
            modification.Sequence = 0;
            modification.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
            modification.Value = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<authorizedType Assembly=\"{0}\" Namespace=\"{1}\" TypeName=\"{2}\" Authorized=\"{3}\"/>", new object[] { "MyCompany.CustomActivities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=207090b9b3f674c8", "MyCompany.CustomActivities", "*", "True" });
            Trace.TraceInformation("SPWebConfigModification value: {0}",modification.Value);
            return modification;        }
```

And the powershell

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "D:\MyCompany.CustomActivitiesActions\MyCompany.CustomConfig\bin\Debug\MyCompany.CustomConfig.wsp" 
Install-SPSolution -Identity MyCompany.CustomConfig.wsp -GACDeployment -Force

Uninstall-SPSolution –Identity MyCompany.CustomConfig.wsp 
Remove-SPSolution –Identity MyCompany.CustomConfig.wsp -force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the SPConfigModification should be the exact xPath to find the element to remove within the container specified by path

In your code you have a Upper/Lowercase error in the name Assembly=\"MyCompany.CustomA**C**tivities... !!! You should use constants (or better get the values from the type) for the values in both Name and Value to make sure they are the same